# Paragraph tag being displayed in new line

Tags: html

I need value "1" to be displayed adjacent to "Id" field but its displaying in a new line.The

tag is supposed to be inline not sure why its being moved to new line.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yL2t7q3u/1/)

HTML

```
<b>Id    : <p id="productid">1</p></b>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#productid{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

p is a block level element by default. You can set it to display inline-block to make it do as you describe using basic css.

I'm not sure if you are unable to access css, so in case you cannot, see oriol's answer. No reason not to just make it a span.

Bit of a side note, it is a little odd to put a p tag inside a b tag. Technically you CAN do this, but it looks like using a span tag is the more proper way to handle this.

Comment: "*Technically you CAN do this*". Not true, [`<p>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-p-element) can only be used where [flow content](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#flow-content-1) is expected, but the content model of [`<b>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-b-element) is [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#phrasing-content-1).

Comment: Not true? Then how did I do it? I didn't say it was a good idea or that it didn't break some kind of standard. I said technically you can do it, which you can by abusing css display overrides like this one. I agree that you should not do this, but I also know we developers don't always have control of what we're given. In those cases, it is good to know you can achieve this with just css, no matter how stupid the decision may be.

Answer (score 1):

A `<p>` element is a paragraph, which by default is a block element.

In this case, you can't use `<p>` because:

- It is not allowed inside `<b>` elements (because [`<p>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-p-element) can only be used where [flow content](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#flow-content-1) is expected, but the content model of [`<b>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-b-element) is [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#phrasing-content-1)). Always remember to [validate](http://validator.w3.org) your code.
- Semantically, it's clear that it isn't a paragraph.

I suggest using

```
<b>Id: <span id="productid">1</span></b>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yL2t7q3u/2/)

Comment: Plusses for the span. This should be the accepted answer because it is the proper use of html.